# Check if a string contains a character ignoring case

Tags: c#, string, contains

I have a textbox on GUI which takes an "Mobile Number" as input. I want to validate it to find out if it has some characters, which would mean the number is invalid

> So, a number   9876543210 is **valid**  while a number 98765df013 is
>   **invalid**

I made a array of all characters (which are not allowed by me)

```
string[] alphabeticChars       = new string[] {    
                                                                    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
                                                                    "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
                                                                    "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
                                                                    "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
                                                               };
```

and then I wrote a validation function

```
public bool HasCharacters(string text)
{
    foreach(string character in this.alphabeticChars)
         if(text.Contains(character.ToLower()) || text.Contains(character.ToUpper())) 
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

As you can see, I need to call Contains twice, one for "Lower Case" and another time for "Upper Case". I checked and couldn't find ContainsIgnoreCase or something.

**What is the best way to to such a thing  ?** (Don't mention regular expressions, as I don't want to use them)

Comment: I suppose I'll be the person that asks: What is the problem with regular expressions here?

Comment: @jdphenix probably because everybody blindly follows this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/ (without completely reading)

Comment: @jdphenix Nothing specific, just wanted to do them by myself.. regular expressions is always something can be handy.. so, first i wanted to explore by myself

Comment: You should edit in your actual requirements to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a very simple way :-)

```
foreach(string character in this.alphabeticChars)
     if(text.ToLower().Contains(character)) 
            return true;
```

Or maybe you can do a regular expression which is more efficient

Comment: Great !. Why on earth did I not think of it.. Thanks !

Comment: I saw your edit, you don't need to convert your character to lower. You control the list of characters and you can take care to have ony lower case.

Answer (score 2):

My answer it is not exactly what you are asking, it more suggestion, better way to validate phone numbers is using of libphonenumber (c#) library https://libphonenumber.codeplex.com that is port of Google libphonenumber. I have found it as the best way to do it for me. You can validate numbers based on country code and to format them in output.

Update.
Here is more up to date version of the library https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  How up-to-date is that, considering that the last activity seems to have been Mon Sep 9, 2013

Comment: @BrendanGreen You can find it on nuget too https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/ there is more up to date version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bool isValid = !text.Any(c => Char.IsLetter(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

My take, using Linq:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsOnlyDigits(this string s)
    {
        return s.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
    }
}
```

And in use:

```
var result = "12345678".ContainsOnlyDigits();
```

Comment: Could be `s.All(Char.IsDigit)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want for test for digits (as your expected input is a "mobile number", it can be a one-liner:

```
bool isValid = text.All(Char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: Well that is a good approach, but tomorrow the requirement might to include special characters like `-` and `+`, in which case `+91-9712712345 `would be a valid result. What could be done in that case

Comment: I would drop the requirement to not use a regular expression and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the presence of a character, switch that logic around and just verify that everything is a number:

```
public bool IsNumeric(string text)
{
    return text.All(char.IsDigit);
}
```